# Как развернуть строки в столбцы по месяцам?

Tags: sql, oracle, запрос, oracle11g, pivot

Есть таблица с полями `(id, name, count, date)`.

Как можно составить запрос, чтобы он выдавал `name` и 12 месяцев со значением `count` в каждом?

То есть, результат запроса должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
name | jan | feb | mar | apr | may | jun | jul | aug | sep | oct | nov | dec

sasha|  1  |  5  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  5  |  7  |  0  |  1  |  3  |  0
petya|  3  |  7  |  2  |  7  |  1  |  0  |  1  |  2  |  1  |  0  |  0  |  1
```

Делал подзапросы, то есть для каждого месяца и каждого имени отдельно просчитывал `count`, получается сильно долгий запрос, несколько минут делается.
Думал про `listagg`, но нужна именно такая таблица в результате.

Comment: А с pivot разве не пробовали? Любой пример который найдёте будет похож на ваш.

Comment: Я бы еще индексы посмотрел. Хорошо чтобы для поля, по которому вы отбираете, он был

Comment: Про pivot вообще не знал, спасибо большое, очень крутая штука)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно с функцией `PIVOT`, с которой [ознакомиться можно тут](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/sql-11g-pivot.html). Воспроизводимый пример:

```sql
with data (name, qty, dt) as (
    select 
        case mod (rownum, 2) when 0 then 'Саша' else 'Петя' end,
        mod (rownum, 2)+1, date'2020-01-01'+(rownum-1) 
    from dual connect by level<=365
) 
--## Отсюда начинается сам запрос
select * from (
    select name, qty, to_char (dt, 'mon') mon from data)
pivot (sum (qty) for mon in (
    'jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec'));
```

Результат (каждый второй день, Петя даёт две единицы, а Саша одну):

```
NAME          'jan'      'feb'      'mar'      'apr'      'may'      'jun'      'jul'      'aug'      'sep'      'oct'      'nov'      'dec'
-------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Петя             32         28         32         30         30         30         32         30         30         32         30         30
Саша             15         15         15         15         16         15         15         16         15         15         15         15
```

Comment: с `case` не сильно хорошо!

Comment: @Yaroslav Извините, а где вы case увидели?

Comment: строка три `case mod (rownum, 2) when 0 then 'Саша' else 'Петя' end,`

Comment: @Yaroslav Хмм, вы знаете что эта строка значит и вообше зачем она здесь?

Comment: думаю что рисует курящих амурских тигров, но вопрос состоит не в этом, что она там делает, а в том зачем там `case`

Comment: Для тех, кто не понял --- часть запроса до `--##` не относиться к решению, и нужна здесь только для того, чтобы автору ответа не нужно было заводить тестовую таблицу с данными. К решению относиться, лишь часть после `--##`. Соответственно в решении `case` нет.

Answer (score 2):

Всё-таки я предложу `case`, дабы не `pivot` единым.

```
select 
  d.name,

  sum(case extract(month from d.date) when 1 then 1 else 0 end) jan,
  sum(case extract(month from d.date) when 2 then 1 else 0 end) feb,
  sum(case extract(month from d.date) when 3 then 1 else 0 end) mar,

  sum(case extract(month from d.date) when 4 then 1 else 0 end) apr,
  sum(case extract(month from d.date) when 5 then 1 else 0 end) may,
  sum(case extract(month from d.date) when 6 then 1 else 0 end) jun,

  sum(case extract(month from d.date) when 7 then 1 else 0 end) jul,
  sum(case extract(month from d.date) when 8 then 1 else 0 end) aug,
  sum(case extract(month from d.date) when 9 then 1 else 0 end) sep,

  sum(case extract(month from d.date) when 10 then 1 else 0 end) oct,
  sum(case extract(month from d.date) when 11 then 1 else 0 end) nov,
  sum(case extract(month from d.date) when 12 then 1 else 0 end) dec

from data d
group by d.name
```

Comment: Ну да, раз кто-то тут case искал, то надо заполнить пробел ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
select
*
from
(select name, count, extract(month from date) mnum from my_table)
pivot
(sum(count) for mnum in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Примерчие без **case** и с полными названияями месяцев.

```
select * from 
( 
    select 
        tDV.testTableName as name, 
        tDV.testTableCount as length, 
        trim(to_char(to_date(tDV.testTableDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'Month')) as month 
    from testTable tDV 
) t 
pivot (sum(lenght) for month in (
    'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'));
```

Вывод:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Извините, не поясните, чем ваше решение отличается от уже ранее предложенных?  О полных названиях месяцев в вопросе не упоминается, **case** тоже никто не предлагал.

Comment: оно без `case`!

Comment: Хорошо, баз case, так без case. Хотел просто понять, что это значит.