# Как задать столбцы для функции PIVOT динамически подзапросом?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, pivot

В [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1117560/217579) стояла задача: развернуть строки в столбцы за 12 месяцев, другими словами кол-во и имена столбцов были заранее известны.

А что если желаемые столбцы в результате заранее неизвестны?

Функция PIVOT допускает использовать подзапрос (или даже ключевое слово ANY) ([см. pivot_in_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6)), но только в сочетании с ключевым словом XML для вывода в XML формате:

> The optional XML keyword generates XML output for the query. The XML keyword permits the pivot_in_clause to contain either a subquery or the wildcard keyword ANY. Subqueries and ANY wildcards are useful when the pivot_in_clause values are not known in advance.

Например, запрос и его результат за весь период будут выглядеть так:

```sql
select * from (
    select name, qty, to_char (dt, 'mon') mon
    from tstdata)
pivot xml (sum (qty) for mon in (select distinct to_char (dt, 'monyy') mon from tstdata))
/
NAME     MON_XML                                                                         
-------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Петя     <PivotSet><item><column name = "MON">apr19</column><column name = "SUM(QTY)"></c
Саша     <PivotSet><item><column name = "MON">apr19</column><column name = "SUM(QTY)"></c
```

А как получить результат сразу в табличном виде и с чем связано это ограничение?

Можно конечно распарсить XML, например, написав PL/SQL табличную функцию, но это ведь не так просто.

---

Генерация тестовых данных [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=435b897461ce969d020bd413007626d5) (см. историю правок, если ссылка недоступна).

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/8759939/6571020

Comment: вы [такой способ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31420487/5741205) не пробовали?

Comment: @MaxU пробовал когда то, вроде работает.

Comment: @MaxU Опубликовал небольшой обзор без-pivot-ников, куда и предложенное вами выше  решение включил.

Answer (score 2):

Столбцы в функции `PIVOT`, их кол-во и тип данных, на момент парсинга (*hard-parse*) должны быть известены. XML результат, это один столбец и тип его известен, отсюда и ограничение.

Самый простое решение, сделать два запроса, первым получить желаемые столбцы, а вторым получить результат для этих столбцов. Как-то так:

```sql
set autoprint on
var rc refcursor
begin
    for r in (
        select listagg (''''||mon||''' '||mon, ',') within group (order by mm) cols 
        from (
            select distinct to_char (dt, 'monyy') mon, to_char (dt, 'yyyymm') mm from tstdata)
        ) loop 
        open :rc for '
            select * from (
                select name, qty, to_char (dt, ''monyy'') mon
                from tstdata)
            pivot (sum (qty) for mon in ('||r.cols||'))';
    end loop;
    if not :rc%isopen then open :rc for select 'no data found' msg from dual; end if; 
end;
/
```

Результат (укорочен для наглядности):

```
NAME          JAN19      FEB19      MAR19      APR19 [...]      NOV20      DEC20
-------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------       ---------- ----------
Петя             32         28         30         30 [...]         30         30
Саша             15         14         16         15 [...]         15         15
```

Answer (score 2):

Существуют также другие решения без функции `PIVOT`, которые пытаются определить столбцы в сете результата динамическии. Как в частности:

- Т.н. [Antons pivoting](https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/) любезно предоставленный участником [@MaxU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1119601/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-pivot-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bc#comment1933584_1119601)
- [Dynamic Pivot PFT](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_HPN95108FSSZD87PXX7MG3LW3.html) пример реализации опубликованный участником [@Chris Saxon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485955/chris-saxon)

Они конечно дают некоторый комфорт по сравнению с [решением с двумя запросами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1119612/217579).
Но сновной принцип остаётся прежним: столбцы в сете результата должны быть известны парсеру SQL; после компиляции запроса, нет никакой возможности изменить столбцы в сете результата.

Посмотрим на примере [Dynamic Pivot with PFT](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_HPN95108FSSZD87PXX7MG3LW3.html), т.к. код на Live SQL проще воспроизвести:

```sql
with rep as (
    select name, to_char (dt, 'yyyy') year  
    from tstdata where name='Саша'
)
select * 
from dynamic_pivot_ptf (
    rep, columns (year), 
    'select distinct to_char (dt, ''yyyy'') from tstdata')
/

NAME           2019       2020
-------- ---------- ----------
Саша            182        183

delete from tstdata where name='Саша' and dt<date'2020-01-01'; 

182 rows deleted.
```

После удаления вроде ожидается, что и столбец `2019` теперь тоже "динамически" исчезнет.
Нет, это не так. Повторите запрос выше. Он не изменился, его скомпилированный байт-код будет вызван из *Library Cache*, соответственно и столбцы в сете результата останутся неизменными:

```
NAME           2019       2020
-------- ---------- ----------
Саша           null        183
```