# Как задать столбцы для транспонирования только средствами SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Как перевернуть строки в столбцы **только средствами SQL** (не PL/SQL) как вот в этом [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1117560/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC) , но мне не нужны все месяцы, а только определённые, сами месяцы я могу получить подзапросом, но в pivot например нельзя использовать подзапрос.

Итак вот что я сам выяснил, есть следующие способы получения сводной таблицы:

- Использовать подзапросы прямо в Select
- Использовать DECODE или CASE
- Использовать функцию PIVOT

Во всех случаях что я видел надо вручную указывать названия столбцов, можно ли как то этого избежать и формировать названия только заданные подзапросом?  Без явного перечисления столбцов.

Если так нельзя сделать, то может можно перечислить все месяцы, но как то скрыть нулевые столбцы месяцев?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15492338/2856962

Comment: А почему вы не посмотрели [связаный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1119601/217579) по ссылке в вашем вопросе? Разве это  не то?

Comment: _только средствами SQL_, увы, [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1342383) подробно расписал - почему не получится.

Comment: @0xdb Похоже единственный выход - попробовать pivot xml, как считаете с ним получится?

Comment: Да, получится, почему нет. Но это тоже фактически два запроса, а не один.