# Запрос на динамику актуального количества сотрудников помесячно

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Есть таблицa `Employees` с колонками (ID сотрудника, ID подразделения, зарплата, дата начала работы, дата окончания работы , ID руководителя):

```
        ID       DEPT     SALARY BEGIN_DA END_DATE     MAN_ID
---------- ---------- ---------- -------- -------- ----------
         1         22    3500,86 01.07.19 01.05.20          1
         1         24    2000,86 01.06.19 01.05.20          2
         2         23    3500,86 01.06.19 01.05.20          2
         3         24    3500,86 01.06.19 01.05.20          3
         4         22    2000,86 01.06.19 01.05.20          3
         7         21    3500,86 01.05.19 01.05.20          1
```

Как посчитать динамику количества сотрудников отделов помесячно в формате:
Отдел,месяц1,месяц2,месяц3, ... итд, за 2019 год?

Пробовал через `with` и аналитическую функцию: `sum() over (partition by)`.
Но значения получились в формате: Отдел, месяц, колличество.

Попробовал пример с Pivot:

```
With t1 as ( 
    Select dept, to_char(begin_date,'mmyyyy') mmyyyy, count (Id) cnt 
    from employees where extract (year from begin_date) = 2019 
    group by dept, to_char(begin_date,'mmyyyy')) 
select * from (select dept, cnt, mmyyyy from t1) 
pivot (sum (cnt) for mmyyyy in (
    '012019','022019','032019','042019','052019','062019',
    '072019','082019','092019','102019','112019','122019'));
```

Но сумма не переходит на след. месяц, т.е. считается количество новых сотрудников в месяц по отделам, а необходимо отследить динамику. Динамика - это актуальное количество сотрудников в отделе помесячно.

[image: Таблица и пример по Pivot]

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Желаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Comment: А [вот это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1117560/217579) не поможет?

Comment: Что значит динамика? На сколько больше или меньше стало с прошлого месяца?

Comment: Раз вам coalesce не пришлось по душе, то убрал его и сделал попроще.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделал бы так:

```
select * from (
    select 
        dept, to_char (m.fday, 'mmyyyy') as mmyyyy, 
        count (case when e.begin_date <= m.fday and m.fday < e.end_date then 1 end) emps
    from employees e 
    cross join (
        select add_months (date'2019-01-01', level-1) fday 
        from dual connect by level <= 12) m 
    group by dept, to_char (m.fday, 'mmyyyy'))
pivot (sum (emps) for mmyyyy in (
    '012019' as "012019",'022019' as "022019",'032019' as "032019",
    '042019' as "042019",'052019' as "052019",'062019' as "062019",
    '072019' as "072019",'082019' as "082019",'092019' as "092019",
    '102019' as "102019",'112019' as "112019",'122019' as "122019"))
/
```

Результат как и ожидался:

```
DEPT 012019 022019 032019 042019 052019 062019 072019 082019 092019 102019 112019 122019
---- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
  22      0      0      0      0      0      1      2      2      2      2      2      2
  21      0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
  23      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
  24      0      0      0      0      0      2      2      2      2      2      2      2
```

---

Запрос и исходные данные на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6198ec86a7dc1a5b8bdb06a31cffc19d).

Answer (score 1):

Идея очень проста нужно лишь правильно суммировать по месяцам, идеи можно черпать отсюда

```
SELECT DEP,  
 SUM(CASE WHEN BEGIN_DATE < Date('2019-02-01') AND (END_DATE IS NULL OR END_DATE >= Date('2019-01-01')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "01.2019",
 SUM(CASE WHEN BEGIN_DATE < Date('2019-03-01') AND (END_DATE IS NULL OR END_DATE >= Date('2019-02-01')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "02.2019",
 SUM(CASE WHEN BEGIN_DATE < Date('2019-04-01') AND (END_DATE IS NULL OR END_DATE >= Date('2019-03-01')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "03.2019",
 SUM(CASE WHEN BEGIN_DATE < Date('2019-05-01') AND (END_DATE IS NULL OR END_DATE >= Date('2019-04-01')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "04.2019",
 SUM(CASE WHEN BEGIN_DATE < Date('2019-06-01') AND (END_DATE IS NULL OR END_DATE >= Date('2019-05-01')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "05.2019",
 SUM(CASE WHEN BEGIN_DATE < Date('2019-07-01') AND (END_DATE IS NULL OR END_DATE >= Date('2019-06-01')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "06.2019",
 SUM(CASE WHEN BEGIN_DATE < Date('2019-08-01') AND (END_DATE IS NULL OR END_DATE >= Date('2019-07-01')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "07.2019",
 SUM(CASE WHEN BEGIN_DATE < Date('2019-09-01') AND (END_DATE IS NULL OR END_DATE >= Date('2019-08-01')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "08.2019",
 SUM(CASE WHEN BEGIN_DATE < Date('2019-10-01') AND (END_DATE IS NULL OR END_DATE >= Date('2019-09-01')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "09.2019",
 SUM(CASE WHEN BEGIN_DATE < Date('2019-11-01') AND (END_DATE IS NULL OR END_DATE >= Date('2019-10-01')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "10.2019",
 SUM(CASE WHEN BEGIN_DATE < Date('2019-12-01') AND (END_DATE IS NULL OR END_DATE >= Date('2019-11-01')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "11.2019",
 SUM(CASE WHEN BEGIN_DATE < Date('2020-01-01') AND (END_DATE IS NULL OR END_DATE >= Date('2019-12-01')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "12.2019"
FROM Employees
WHERE
    EXTRACT( year FROM BEGIN_DATE) < 2020 -- устроился до 2020 года, можно исключить это условие
     AND (END_DATE IS NULL -- работает до сих пор
          OR EXTRACT( year from END_DATE) > 2018) -- уволился до 2019
GROUP BY 
DEP
```

Я не стал добавлять начальника отдела так как в течении года может смениться он.